# Multiple TeamCity agents - Where is code check out

Tags: teamcity

I have a default agent on the build server and when it is run - it checked out the code in the server folders and running builds off it. Then I have another teamcity build agent installed on another machine (test server)

TeamCity Documentation says

> "To be capable of getting project sources, Build Agents are not
>   required to have any pre-configured Version Control System on them.
>
> Build Agents don't need to have any VCS systems installed on them as
>   the sources are checked out on the server-side. Thus, lesser effort is
>   required to maintain the company's infrastructure."

The source is checked out server side - If an agent installed on a test server is run, will there be code check out in another new folder on the server ? or will it run builds off the same already existing code check out folders (the one the default agent on the server is working off)

Answer (score 1):

The former is true: TeamCity will check out a clean copy of code from source control for each VCS root/build agent combination, via the central TC webserver (if using server side checkout). Whether subsequent builds use the cached copy of sources or retrieve from source control again is based on a number of factors, including:

- Whether clean checkout is turned on in the build configuration
- Whether TC cleaned up your sources to free up disk space as part of an unrelated build
- Build history cleanup rules (this definitely cleans up artifacts/previous builds, not sure about sources)
- Other internal TC rules not understood by mere morals such as us

So to clarify, when using server-side checkout, the agent always relies on the server to retrieve the code from source control on its behalf, but the agents themselves are responsible for managing the source caches.

Comment: restating what you said.. "The former is true: TeamCity will check out a clean copy of code from source control for each VCS root/build agent combination, ....." -- in newly created folders? I need to know if new folders are created for each such VCS root/build agent combination. If there are 5 build remote agents, there are 5 copies of code on the server?

Comment: Ah I see what you're asking. No I believe that TC only keeps a temporary copy on the server for as long as it takes it to pass the code through to the agent, the it removes it (I'd need to confirm that though) May I ask what your driving concern is? eg Is it disk space usage?

Comment: Disk usage is one thing, but I wanted to know how remote build agent works in concept. So you are saying my remote agent will work on the single copy of server code(checked out from TFS). But after I install a remote agent on a remote machine, I see the buildagent creates a folder with a 'work' subfolder in the remote machine? Not sure why there is a need for this, when the agent is working off of the server copy.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, perhaps I wasn't clear. The build agent doesn't work directly on the server copy, but rather it takes a local copy of the sources so that the agent doesn't need to continually transfer all the code every time a build is requested. This is particularly important in situations where the connection between your build agent and TC server is slow.